# Useful new .net(3.0,4.0) technology features

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-4.0, language-features

Previously it was .net 2.0 which is the big change in .net developement. many developers are working mostly on this. Presently microsoft has introduced .net 3.0 and yet its next version .net 4.0. So the next version is going to be major change in .net development.

I have listed some features of this...

Workflow foundation
WPF
WCF
Windows cardspace
Agile methodalogy implementation.
Silverlight features enhancement.

In the new generation framework what are the features that you like and why it attracts you.

Comment: See this Question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138367/most-wanted-feature-for-c-4-0

Answer (score 4):

You missed .NET 3.5, which is actually a bigger package than .NET 3.0; .NET 3.0 adds things like WCF/WPF/WF, which are nicer ways to do things that were (generally) already there in the framework.

However, .NET 3.5 adds LINQ, which is *huge* and broad-reaching. LINQ-to-Objects is the most used, providing a more convenient model for regular code. But LINQ-to-SQL, and EF (in SP1) are ORM tools (with many others available).

.NET 4.0 targets a few problems, in particular threading (TPL/CCR) and dynamic objects (DLR). C# 4.0 has *mainly* changes to make dynamic objects easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking which new features will the upcoming .NET 4.0 Framework present, I've heard a lot about Parallel Computing, specifically about a Task Parallel Library built in the core of the Framework, also [PLinq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163329.aspx) or Parallel Linq, focusing on LINQ-to-Objects and LINQ-to-XML .

Check te [Microsoft PDC Website](http://www.microsoftpdc.com/) and you'll find more interesting info.

Answer (score 0):

I **really** loves lambda expressions. It makes things so much easier! I also look forward to some of the features in C# 4.0, such as optional parameters, named parameters, No PIA and much more. :-)

Comment: Minor clarification: expression trees are a runtime (3.5) feature. Lambdas, however, can be seen as a language feature (C# 3.0) and are usable with .NET 2.0. Either way, yes: they're good ;-p